# Double association between 2 tables with Doctrine2 PHP

Tags: php, database, postgresql, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to do an association of 5 objects with Doctrine2 (PHP).
I'm using PostgreSQL.

Here is the Database schema:
[Database schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLAB8.png)

A company may have many Hubs, each Hub have one Harbor.
A company may have many Line, each Line have a Linelist.
A Linelist have 2 Harbors.
For example, a Linelist is "Los Angeles-Seattle", and multiple companies may own it thanks to the Line table.

I'm trying to query all the Hub, Harbor, Linelist, and Line for one company.
I have the SQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM hub h
JOIN harbor a
ON a.id = h.harbor_id
JOIN linelist l
ON (l.harborstart_id = a.id OR l.harborend_id = a.id)
JOIN line m
ON m.linelist_id = l.id
WHERE h.company_id = 41
AND m.company_id = 41"
```

I'm trying to do the same using DQL.
I tried this, but it doesn't worked:

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()
->createQuery('SELECT h, a, l, m
               FROM AmGameBundle:Hub h
               JOIN h.harbor a
               JOIN a.linelist l
               JOIN l.line m
               WHERE h.company = :company_id
               AND m.company = :company_id')
->setParameter('company_id', $company_id);
```

As a result, I only have the LineList and Line objects matching harborstart_id, but I want the one matching either harborstart_id or harborend_id.

Do you think this is possible in DQL?
It might be better to change the relation between Harbor and Linelist for a many to many?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's a matter of defining 2 relations from *harbor* to *linelist* in your Entities.  I imagine you have something like

```
<?php
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="LineList")
 */
class LineList {
    /** 
     * @var object $startHarbor
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Harbor", inversedBy="startHarbors")
     * @JoinColumn(name="harborstart_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=FALSE)
     */
    protected $startHarbor;
}

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="Harbor")
 */
class Harbor {
    /** 
     * @var object $startHarbors
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="LineList", mappedBy="startHarbor")
     */
    protected $startHarbors;
}
```

That will let you join Harbors to LineLists via **harborstart_id** (you named the variable *linelist*, but I think now it's better to change the identifiers as there will be 2 referring to the same foreign table), then if you want to **harborend_id**

```
<?php
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="LineList")
 */
class LineList {
    /** 
     * @var object $startHarbor
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Harbor", inversedBy="startHarbors")
     * @JoinColumn(name="harborstart_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=FALSE)
     */
    protected $startHarbor;

    /** 
     * @var object $endHarbor
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Harbor", inversedBy="endHarbors")
     * @JoinColumn(name="harborend_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=FALSE)
     */
    protected $endHarbor;
}

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="Harbor")
 */
class Harbor {
    /** 
     * @var object $startHarbors
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="LineList", mappedBy="startHarbor")
     */
    protected $startHarbors;

    /** 
     * @var object $endHarbors
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="LineList", mappedBy="endHarbor")
     */
    protected $endHarbors;
}
```

Now you can change the DQL to:

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()
->createQuery('SELECT h, a, sh, eh, m
               FROM AmGameBundle:Hub h
               JOIN h.harbor a
               JOIN a.startHarbors sh
               JOIN a.endHarbors eh
               JOIN l.line m
               WHERE h.company = :company_id
               AND m.company = :company_id')
->setParameter('company_id', $company_id);
```

That should get you in the right direction.  If it becomes troublesome though, a many-to-many approach as you speculated should be a well documented solution.

Comment: You might just want to go straight to many-to-many, check out this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919910/is-it-possible-to-reference-a-column-other-than-id-for-a-joincolumn/8959222#8959222