# Is it possible to reference a column other than 'id' for a JoinColumn?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have an `Item` entity that has a `ManyToOne` relationship to a `Category` entity. I want them to be joined by a field other than Category's `id` (in this case, a field called `id2`). My schema is listed below.

```
class Item {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name = "id", type = "integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy = "AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity = "Category")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name = "category_id", referencedColumnName = "id2")
     */
    protected $category;
}

class Category {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name = "id", type = "integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy = "AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name = "id2", type = "string", length = "255", unique = "true")
     */
    protected $id2;
```

When I try saving an `Item` I get this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: id2 in vendor/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php line 511

Sure enough, if I change `id2` to `id` in the `JoinColumn` annotation, everything works fine, but I need the entities to be connected through `id2`. Is this possible?

**Edit**
What I want to achieve is impossible according to the official Doctrine 2 docs.

> It is not possible to use join columns pointing to non-primary keys.
>   Doctrine will think these are the primary keys and create lazy-loading
>   proxies with the data, which can lead to unexpected results. Doctrine
>   can for performance reasons not validate the correctness of this
>   settings at runtime but only through the Validate Schema command.

source: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/limitations-and-known-issues.html#join-columns-with-non-primary-keys

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think Doctrine wants these to be primary keys, from [the docs](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-joincolumn):

> name: Column name that holds the foreign key identifier for this relation.

Another thing that jumps out at me from your code sample is *category.id2* being *type* **string**, I would at least expect it to be an **integer**, but it may also need to be for **@JoinColumn** to work properly.

You may be able to get away with just [@Index](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-index) on *category.id2* and leave it as a **string** though; worth a shot anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried changing the field type to integer, and adding @Index, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Bah!  Looks like they need to be fks after all.  There's always many-to-many as an option.

Answer (score 4):

Just to report. I was able to join non-PKs in Many2One (undirectional) relation, BUT my object can't be loaded the normal way. It must be loaded with DQL like:

```
SELECT d,u FROM DEntity d
    JOIN d.userAccount u
```

this way I stopped getting error: Missing value for primary key id on ....