# Doctrine 2 mapping referencing unique key

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

**Basic question:**

Is it possible to map an association using Doctrine referencing not a primary but only a unique key?

**Extended Version:**

I have an Entity (`Participation`) which **may** reference 2 other entities (`DropoutCause` and `DischargeType`). Depending on this combination some other attributes are implied, based on another (4th) table (`DropoutScenario`) in database. Because either of both referenced entities may be null I couldn't declare them as primary but only unique key in the 4th table.

The problem is I only get an error when I try to map this with Doctrine:

> Missing value for primary key id on
>   Application\Entity\Trainings\DropoutScenario

Am I doing something wrong, or is this simply not possible with Doctrine?
If not, is there any better solution how I could do this?

I've been searching for quite a long time now and dug the Doctrine documentation but I simply couldn't find anything on this...

Stripped code samples of my mappings are below.

**Participation:**

```
<?php

namespace Application\Entity\Trainings;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 */
abstract class Participation {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\DropoutCause")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="dropout_cause_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
     */
    protected $dropoutCause;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\DischargeType")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="discharge_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
     */
    protected $dischargeType;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="DropoutScenario")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="discharge_id", referencedColumnName="discharge_id"),
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="dropout_cause_id", referencedColumnName="dropout_cause_id")
     * })
     */
    private $scenario;
```

**DropoutScenario:**

```
<?php

namespace Application\Entity\Trainings;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="training_dropout_scenarios")
 */
class DropoutScenario {

    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\DropoutCause")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="dropout_cause_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
     */
    protected $dropoutCause;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\DischargeType")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="discharge_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
     */
    protected $dischargeType;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="dropout_cause_id") */
    protected $dropoutCauseId;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="discharge_id") */
    protected $dischargeTypeId;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since I did not get any answer yet I did another research today and I found the answer to my own question through the Doctrine mailing lists forum.
Seems like I just searched for the wrong keywords...

**Doctrine 2 unfortunately does not support it. What a pity! :(**

From the Doctrine documentation:
https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/limitations-and-known-issues.html#join-columns-with-non-primary-keys

> It is not possible to use join columns pointing to non-primary keys.
>   Doctrine will think these are the primary keys and create lazy-loading
>   proxies with the data, which can lead to unexpected results. Doctrine
>   can for performance reasons not validate the correctness of this
>   settings at runtime but only through the Validate Schema command.

Similar question:
[Is it possible to reference a column other than 'id' for a JoinColumn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919910/is-it-possible-to-reference-a-column-other-than-id-for-a-joincolumn)

Answer (score 0):

Just like following references, Doctrine does not support this type of mapping

[http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-1269](https://web.archive.org/web/20111229134320/http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-1269)

[http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-1114](https://web.archive.org/web/20111229155509/http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-1114)

I think it will be helps to you.

Comment: Need to delete this because links are expired.

Answer (score 0):

My two cents for this very old question.

Its true that Doctrine 2 does not support mapping relation to a non primary key mapped column, however its possible to simulate it.

[OneToOne Mapping example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HV9zi.png)

Example in yml format:

```
### UserEntity.dcm.yml
UserEntity:
type: entity
repositoryClass: UserRepository
table: User
id:
  id:
    type: integer
      nullable: false
      length: 9
      options:
        unsigned: true
      id: true
      column: id
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
  fields:
    status:
      type: integer
      nullable: false
      length: 2
      options:
        fixed: false
      column: status
    dateOfBirth:
      type: datetime
      nullable: true
      options:
        fixed: false
      column: date_of_birth
    createdAt:
      type: datetime
      nullable: true
      options:
        fixed: false
      column: created_at
  userAvatar:
    targetEntity: AvatarEntity
    joinColumn:
      name: id
      referencedColumnName: user_id
  lifecycleCallbacks: {  }


### AvatarEntity.dcm.yml
User/AvatarEntity:
  type: entity
  repositoryClass: AvatarRepository
  table: Avatar
  id:
    userId:
      type: integer
      nullable: false
      length: 9
      options:
        unsigned: true
      id: true
      column: user_id
      generator:
        strategy: NONE
  fields:
    imageName:
      type: string
      nullable: false
      length: 255
      options:
        fixed: false
      column: image_name
  lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

With this yml we now can get the **Avatar** entry through ***user_id*** column like primary key from User.
With the ***id*** definition poiting to this column on **AvatarEntity.dcm.yml** and the ***oneToOne*** relation on **UserEntity.dcm.yml** we do the trick and the resultant SQL will be correct like we want.