# Missing value for primary key id Doctrine Symfony2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm working on a join between two entities in doctrine on symphony 2.8.2. I keep getting "Missing value for primary key id"

Heres the id annotation for the missing id.

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;
```

Here are my joins:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="FYP\BaseDesignBundle\Entity\SessionDesign", inversedBy="user")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="fcid", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $sessionDesign;


/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="FYP\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="sessionDesign")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="fcid")
 */
private $user;
```

Comment: Is it intentional that you have two "inversedBy" between SessionDesign and User?

Comment: No its not intentional, I didn't catch that. Unfortunately though that doesn't fix it.

Comment: Is your problem still persisting ?

Comment: Yeah that wasn't the fix.

Comment: symfony, not symphony probably

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a mistake coming from the `joinColumn` name of your association.

Change your mapping to :

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="FYP\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="sessionDesign")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $user;
```

Note: That is the default configuration, also the line can be removed because it's useless.

**EDIT**

I was right without pointing the real problem.
You are getting this error because you are trying to use a column that is not a primary key as the `referencedColumnName` of your `joinColumn`

The following:

```
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="fcid")
```

Should be:

```
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
```

From [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059666/doctrine-2-mapping-referencing-unique-key) at [the owner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24364419/4363634) (related to the exactly same error):

> It is not possible to use join columns pointing to non-primary keys. Doctrine will think these are the primary keys and create lazy-loading proxies with the data, which can lead to unexpected results. Doctrine can for performance reasons not validate the correctness of this settings at runtime but only through the Validate Schema command.
>
> Similar question [Is it possible to reference a column other than 'id' for a JoinColumn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919910/is-it-possible-to-reference-a-column-other-than-id-for-a-joincolumn)

Comment: So is it possible to do a join with two none primary keys then?

Comment: Ok what I don't understand though is that id is a primary key for sessionDesign, and fcid is a foreign reference to it.

Comment: That's it. The join column must be a non-primary key, but the reference must be. Look at the relation view of a table in your phpMyAdmin, you will see : `column "foo_id" => foreign key constraint => "bartable.id"` .  The first is the join, the last is the reference (primary key of the target table).

Comment: From your first question: Is it possible to do a join with two none-primary keys, no it's not possible. I misunderstood. Also is your question answered ?

Comment: Only way is to "hack" it by setting the referenced column as `#[ORM\Id]` however that is obviously not always possible.