# Adding additional foreign key constraint to Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have entity SomeMainEntity which extends MainEntity.  SomeMainEntity contains GroupEntity as well as a collection of SubEntity's.  SQL will be:

MainEntity

- id (autoincrement integer PK)

SomeMainEntity extends MainEntity

- id (association=true => one-to-one PK/FK to main_entity.id)
- group_entity_id (many-to-one FK to group_entity.id)

GroupEntity

- id (autoincrement integer PK)

SubEntity

- id (autoincrement integer PK)
- some_main_entity_id (many-to-one FK to some_main_entity.id)
- name

Now, I wish to change SubEntity so that name is unique for a given GroupEntity within SomeMainEntity.  I tried the following:

SubEntity

- id (autoincrement integer PK)
- some_main_entity_id (many-to-one FK to some_main_entity.id, FK to some_main_entity.group_entity_id)
- name

But this apparently will not work because some_main_entity id/group_entity_id evidently must be a composite PK.  Also, since SomeMainEntity extends MainEntity, this gets a bit tricky if not impossible.  I also tried creating a unique key in SomeMainEntity, but Doctrine does not appear to support (https://stackoverflow.com/a/24364419/1032531)

As another attempt, I added GroupEntity as a property in SubEntity

SubEntity

- id (autoincrement integer PK)
- some_main_entity_id (many-to-one FK to some_main_entity.id)
- group_entity_id (many-to-one FK to group_entity.id)
- name

Now, I can add a unique constraint between name and group_entity_id, however, this really isn't right because it does not ensure that the given associated MainEntity also contains this same GroupEntity.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: really depends on your use case, but there are symfony/doctrine constraints that ensure certain things like uniqueness of a combination of fields, however no garantees.https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html

Comment: @Jakumi  Thanks.  While I indirectly use Symfony, I don't directly use the framework.  Guess I could use some sort of lifecycle event.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up taking a more tradition SQL approach which was easy to implement using Doctrine.

First three tables remained the same:

**MainEntity**

- id (autoincrement integer PK)

**SomeMainEntity extends MainEntity**

- id (association=true => one-to-one PK/FK to main_entity.id)
- group_entity_id (many-to-one FK to group_entity.id)

**GroupEntity**

- id (autoincrement integer PK)

Then added an extra table:

**MainEntityHasGroupEntity**

- mainEntityId (Composite PK and FK to MainEntity.id.  Add UNIQUE index)
- groupEntityId (Composite PK and FK to GroupEntity.id)

And then used that extra table on the last table:

**SubEntity**

- id (autoincrement integer PK)
- mainEntityId (FK to MainEntityHasGroupEntity.mainEntityId)
- groupEntityId (FK to MainEntityHasGroupEntity.groupEntityId)
- name