# Doctrine foreign key working on one index but not another?

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony

So I am trying to setup a system where multiple tables have rows that can be in one of many states that can be easily viewed directly in the table without going to a lookup table. So I am using doctrine and I have a ManyToOne relationship that **is working correctly** when I use referencedColumnName="id".

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="DataBundle\State", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="State", referencedColumnName="id" )
 */
protected $State;
```

However once I change referencedColumnName to name (the value I actually want) this does not work and I get "General Error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint"

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="DataBundle\State", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="State", referencedColumnName="name" )
 */
protected $State;
```

My goal is to have any table I drop this in to have a column State that is in one of my states with the state name visible. Right now it works and the foreign key gets setup but it only shows the ID, once I change to name I get the error. For clarity my State table has 2 Columns, id and name one is an int and the other is a varchar 255.

I have read that this could be because of differing DB engines, or different data types. All engine types are the same and I am not defining the $State column's type anywhere, it is being inherited from doctrine. Any ideas?

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919910/is-it-possible-to-reference-a-column-other-than-id-for-a-joincolumn)

Comment: Drop this as a comment and I will accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not correct to have a [@JoinColumn](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-joincolumn) based on different [Datatypes](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html).

You can do the job with a Column state on your main entity, just restrict your queries with an 'state' flag (with datatype boolean or integer). I think that it would be a better idea.

It will be possible than I don't really understand what is the goal your want to achieve.